# User Role plugin to restrict editing to specific Categories for Pages

Tags: wordpress

I need a plugin that would restrict registered users to only be able to add/edit **pages** in specific categories. Even though WordPress pages do not have "Categories" like posts do.

Like, if I have a category called "Robot Maintenance", I want to make sure that only specified users or roles can edit and create pages in that category.

I see that the [Member](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) plugin lets me create new roles with such capabilities as "edit only pages they own" but I was hoping I could create a role (for say, a department) and configure that role to be able to edit and create pages within the {department} category. Or even limit users to specific categories.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly complex task, and you may want to engage a professional wordpress plugin developer to build this for you.

Having said that....

It is possible to add categories to a page. Check out the tutorial at http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-tags-and-categories-to-your-wordpress-page

Next, you will want to programatically create roles for each page category you have. You will want to hook into the create and remove category to create/remove your special role. Then, you can use the members plugin to grant proper permissions.

Then, you need to hook into the page edit flow to ensure that the current user has the permissions to edit the current page (based on your custom roles and the page's category).

Still a bit of work for you to research...but at least this should give you a fairly good starting point.